# set jsonarray list into autocompletetextview

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to fetch list of services from web service and add it to autocompletetextview. So suppose if you enter `"a"`, you will get the below list of services in the autocompletetextview. I think its a json array but I'm getting error `"Json error: Value Body Spa at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray".` Please correct me if I'm doing this the wrong way.

```css
// you get this json response on entering "a"

[
  "Body Spa",
  "Hair Cut",
  "Hair massage",
  "fghfghfgh",
  "rtyrt",
  "Gold Facial",
  "Foot's massage"
]
```

```html
public class HomeOptionTwo extends Fragment implements TextWatcher{

    AutoCompleteTextView autoservice;
    String[] list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private static final String SERVICE = "http://192.168.200.1/android/spaservice";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homeoptiontwo, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        autoservice = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.service);


        autoservice.addTextChangedListener(this);





    }

    private void prepareMyList() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVICE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            //JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "services:" + jsonarray.getJSONArray(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        getActivity(),
                                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                        list);

                                autoservice.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }





                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("'phrase", autoservice.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        prepareMyList();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: JSONArray is containing list of strings, you are fetching array from array which is incorrect.
Change your toast to
`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "services:" + jsonarray.getString(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: you dont need any `TextWatcher` / `addTextChangedListener` nor async voley requests, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: I'm using volley as the web service filters the total list of 36 items according to the text entered. Now my current prob is I'm getting all 36 items even when I enter some text which should reduce the item list. @pskink

Comment: did you see the link i posted?

Comment: Yes, but I want volley request as I get different items on different text entered(filteration is done at API level). I got what's the error now. I'm getting the items list with 4 times repetition. @pskink

Comment: did you check when `runQuery` is called? watch the logcat when you are entering some text in ACTV, just copy/paste those ~30 lines of code to your `onCreate` method and run

Comment: I think I need to clear the adapter as if I don't previous list will get added to my current list. Can you tell me where I should use `adapter.clear()` in my current code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112647/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
     "services:" + jsonarray.getJSONArray(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`jsonarray` contains String as item instead of JSONArray. use `optString` or `getString` to get value from `jsonarray` JSONArray using index. like:

```
ArrayList<String> arrList=new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   String strValue=jsonarray.optString(i);                             
   arrList.add(strValue);
 }
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                arrList);

  autoservice.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now atleast I got what was wrong. Its working good now. @ρяσѕρєя K.

Comment: If it helped, kindly accept the answer to make it closed.